# Use JsRender to create a row/column layout from simple array data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

I am using `jsrender` to write a bootstrap based HTML template and render the HTML content using javascript. My data is as follows

```
var data = [
    {
        'img': 'img/books/kiterunner.jpg',
        'title': 'The Kite Runner',
        'authors': 'Khaled Hosseini'
    },
    {
        'img': 'img/books/tokillamockingbird.jpg',
        'title': 'To Kill A Mocking Bird',
        'authors': 'Harper Lee'
    },
    {
        'img': 'img/books/hungergames.jpg',
        'title': 'The Hunger Games',
        'authors': 'Suzanne Collins'
    }
    .....
]
```

And the corresponding HTML I want to generate is as follows

```
<div class="row-fluid" id="result">
    <script id="template" type="text/x-js-render">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="image-tile outer-title text-center">
                <img alt="{{:title}}" src="{{:img}}" style="max-height:350px;">
                <div class="title mb16">
                    <h5 class="uppercase mb0">{{:title}}</h5>
                        <span>{{:authors}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
   </script>
</div>
```

Currently each object in `data` gets displayed individually but sometimes, the images are larger in size and disrupt the way the row looks. So I want to repeat the `div.row-fluid` creation with the content after every `4` objects from `data`. I currently do the following to register the template and render the data into the required HTML. I can't seem to figure out how to use `{{for}}` without changing the values in `data`.

```
var template = $.templates("#template");
var htmlOutput = template.render(data);
$("#result").html(htmlOutput);
```

Thank you.

Edit: I have managed to do this by doing explicit HTML string concatenation and then rendering them while using `index%4` in the `if` statements to decide on whether the `div.row-fluid` needs to be created. However, I would really like a more elegant solution. Adding `jquery` tag for wider visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom `{{range}}` tag - see [this sample](http://www.jsviews.com/#tags@range-sample).

Here is an example which renders into a table with `<td>`s grouped by four - for a four column layout:

```
<script id="myTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <table>
    {{for rows ~last=rows.length-1}}
      {{if #index%4===0 ~ind=#index}}
        <tr>
        {{range ~root.rows start=~ind end=~ind+3 max=~last}}
          <td>{{:title}}</td>
        {{/range}}
        </tr>
      {{/if}}
    {{/for}}
  </table>
</script>
```

using this version of a custom `{{range}}` tag:

```
$.views.tags("range", function(array) {
  var ret = "",
    start = this.tagCtx.props.start,
    end = this.tagCtx.props.end,
    max = this.tagCtx.props.max;

  end = end > max ? max : end;

  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    // Render tag content, for this data item
    ret += this.tagCtx.render(array[i]);
  }
  return ret;
});

var data = {rows: [
    {
        'title': ...
    },
    ...
  ]};

  ...
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much @BorisMoore
If you liked the question, I'd appreciate an upvote on it.

Comment: The scenario is a good one. The formulation/code is a bit strange since you want the div.row-fluid to repeat every four items, but you show it *outside* the template declaration, as if you want to have multiple template declaration instances. Multiple declarations of the same template should generally be avoided, and a template is generally only compiled once.